# I need a Hexadecimal Number List

Tags: numbers, hex

I need a script that generates all 65536 Hexadecimal numbers from 0000 to FFFF and puts them in a text file like this:

```
0000  
0001  
0002  
0003  
...  
FFFF
```

I don`t care what programming language it is written in, but please not one that I have to run a web server (PHP) or that is Windows only.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please go to https://www.freelancer.com/. I'm sure someone will be more then happy to help.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codegolf.se]

Comment: I actually wrote a set of python scripts for [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/x2x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    for(long i = 0x0; i <= 0xFFFF ; i++){
        printf("%X\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? because it works for me.

Comment: hex.c: In function ‘main’:
hex.c:3:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
     for(long i = 0x0; i <= 0xFFFF ; i++){
     ^
hex.c:3:5: note: use option -std=c99, -std=gnu99, -std=c11 or -std=gnu11 to compile your code
hex.c:4:9: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%X\n", i);

Comment: Understand the error message and debug . Do you expect everything to be spoon fed ? Just declare i outside the for loop . I use mac and it has clang not gcc..

Comment: Thanks man :) But now how i can save it to txt file?

Comment: pipe it to a file  .

Comment: Last think, how i can make it always 4 Digits?

Comment: printf("%000X\n",i) maybe ?

Comment: ah.. its "%04X\n" actually.

Answer (score 1):

the core is a Python one liner :

```
a = [hex(x) for x in xrange(0,pow(2, 16))]
```

or

```
a = map(hex, xrange(pow(2,16)))


print A
```

the rest is slicing out 'oxd' and writing to your file ie

```
f = open('workfile.txt', 'w')

for x in a:
    f.write(x[3:])
```

Comment: Sorry i don`t know Python. Can you write it so that i can run it?

Comment: [on paste bin](http://pastebin.com/up2Gx4kN)

Comment: Thanks, but it goes only up to FFF and i need up to FFFF. How i can make it? Also, how i can make it doing 0001 instead of 1. I need that to be every time 4 digits.